# ZF3 Skeleton - Manual cache disable ignored - unless via Composer

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

The docs and tutorials for ZF3 all say that you should enable "Development mode" locally during development to disable the cache. Now, this is fine, and when you use `composer development-enable` or `*-disable`, the command copies `/config/development.config.php.dist`, removes the `.dist` extension and places it next to the dist file.

Doing this successfully disables the caching due the config within that file.

However, when doing it manually with the following config, the caching **does not** get disabled when running Terminal commands. However, they **are disabled** when running Terminal commands **with** the `development.config.php` file present.

This is my `application.config.php` file atm:

```
$env = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'); // Expect null or "development"

return [
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',
    'module_listener_options' => [
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],
        'config_cache_enabled'      => $env === 'development' ? false : true,
        'config_cache_key'          => 'application.config.cache',
        'module_map_cache_enabled'  => $env === 'development' ? false : true,
        'module_map_cache_key'      => 'application.module.cache',
        'cache_dir'                 => 'data/cache/',
        'check_dependencies'       => $env === 'development' ? true : false,
    ],
];
```

Just removed all the comments, bunched it all up, lined it out, and setting the `true/false` based on a server environment variable.

I'm using Apache, so the below vhost config works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/skeleton"
    ServerName skeleton.loc

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've confirmed this with debugging:

[image: debug image]

**The question is:** How come, when I use this last manual route, caching does not get disabled?

It keeps creating the cache files that are configured to be created when `$env` does not equal `"development"`. However, it bloody shouldn't and it's cause for a great deal of frustration.

(Yes yes, for now I'll use the setting via Composer, i.e. having the additional config file, but I shouldn't have to!)

Comment: sis you remove "development.config.php" file?

Comment: Doing both. Using "delete" and `composer development-disable` to test this phenomenon. However, as stated in question, manually **adding** the file, is not enough to **enable**. It does something else, somewhere... My question is "what?" so that I can maybe create a work-around for it.